# Replacing old bathroom fan/heater/light switch

Tags: switch

Not changing the fan, but wanted to change out switch.  This is what I'm seeing so I'm not sure what is going on. Thoughts?[image]

Comment: If the white on the left of the left-most switch is "hot to one of the lamp/heat/fan units" and the "black to the other white" is just a straight unbroken contact (not switched) then it would make sense that the diagonal whites pass the hot from one switch to another.  Without an ohmmeter, that's just an educated guess.

Comment: "black to the other white", what do you mean?  It's a bad pic with bad lighting but there are 3 black wires.

Comment: Those wires look [white and gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dress) to me...

Comment: What is wrong with the switch *now*? Does it work in all respects?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, but replacing with new white one.  Also thinking about removing heater from it, so going down to 2 switch from 3.  Better pic attached now.

Comment: What I mean by "black to the other white": On the left-most switch, there's a white wire with a nick in the jacket (on the left) and then a second white wire.  That second white wire could be connected to the black internally (long-ways) inside the switch itself.  (On the second switch are two whites.  If what I'm suggesting is true, those two whites are also connected together.)